# How to Resolve Type Mismatch in Hibernate Projection?

Tags: java, hibernate

```
ProjectionList projectionsList = Projections.projectionList();
projectionsList.add(Projections.property("userMasterTable.userCreatedDateTime"), "createdDateTime");
criteria.setProjection(projectionsList);
criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Users.class));
allUsers=criteria.list(); //allUsers is a List
```

**userCreatedDateTime** is of Date Type.

**createdDateTime** is of String Type.

when I tried to run this code, its showing type mismatch exception.
How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you use projection param as String value --> "createdDateTime" , use it as object.

```
Projections.property("userMasterTable.userCreatedDateTime"), createdDateTime);
```

If createdDateTime has String type then convert it into DateTime with DateTimeFormat

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(createdDateTime);
```